# Atom Editor - How to fix: Only one tab open at a time

Tags: view, tabs, atom-editor

I have a cat. She likes to sit on my keyboard.

I recently downloaded the Atom Editor, and I love it, but I don't know much about the settings. I just came back to having about 50 instances of Atom opened... bc... #catflife. I had to restart the computer.

Right now my window shows the "Project" pane to the left, and an open file on the right. Normally, I can click on "main.js" and "style.css" , and both files will be open on the right side pane, like tabs.

However, only one file is showing. I would like for the tabs to look like this:

```
style.css | main.js | anotherfile.php | anotherfile.js
```

But, let's say I click on "style.css" - it appears on the right side. Then I click on "main.js", and the stylesheet disappears (from the right side) and is replaced with "main.js".

Not sure which setting my cat changed, but how do I change it back to seeing a tab view on the right side?

Comment: If the answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. This will help others with the same problem to find the solution quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on a file in Atom, its pane is only ”pending” until you make changes to that file. From then on, a second file will be opened in a new pane. The pending state is indicated by the italic text on the tab.

[image]

You can force opening a new file by *double-clicking* on the file. Or you can disable pending panes in the settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your furry friend disabled/removed the tabs package

File-> Settings -> Packages
search for tabs(v0.110.0) and ensure it is installed and enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on a file in the project tree. Then click split Left/right.